# mysqli query for no results do something else do something else

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm running a mysqli query.

this is my code

```
<?php
    $SM_pro_info="SELECT * FROM special_marketing_ads ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 4";
    $QSM_pro_info = $db->query($SM_pro_info)or die($db->error);
        if($QSM_pro_info->num_rows > 0){
        while($SM_pro=$QSM_pro_info->fetch_object()){



    ?>
      <table width="208" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="129" height="35" align="right"><span style="color:#361800; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $SM_pro->pro_title; ?></span></td>
          <td width="69" rowspan="2" align="center"><a rel="lightbox" href="includes/Cpanel/projectImages//images.jpg" ><img src="<?php echo $SM_pro->image_1; ?>" alt="" width="60" height="60" border="0" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="right">
          <td><span style="color:#361800; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">الغرض</span> : <span style="color:#da6e19; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $SM_pro->pro_purpose; ?></span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <?php
        }
        }else{
            for ($x=0; $x<(4 - $QSM_pro_info->num_rows); $x++) {
            echo 'Your ad here'; // or, whatever your ad text is
            }
            }
      ?>
    </div>
```

now all I want to do is if there is any results comeing from mysqli echo it if there is no results it should
echo an image which is add your ads here. the point is I have 4 Ads so if there is 1 Ads in mysqli row and the others is empty so I want it to echo this single Ads and the other 3 Ads should be this image add your Ads here.
any Help on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
if($QSM_pro_info->num_rows ==1){
```

To this:

```
if ($QSM_pro_info->num_rows > 0) {
```

The issue is that you were checking for exactly one result.  What you want is more than zero results.

Now, in the part where you display "your ads here", try this:

```
for ($x=0; $x<(4 - $QSM_pro_info->num_rows); $x++) {
    echo 'Your ad here'; // or, whatever your ad text is
}
```

Also be sure to use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) around your variable data in HTML, to avoid broken HTML (and potential XSS attacks, depending on your data source).

Comment: hay Brad I got it running but my question that I made a limit 4 in mysql and I need this text "put your ads here" to appear 4 times if there is no results from the table and if there is two rows it should echo the two rows and the other two should be still has this text "add your ads here" any help on this?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now.  You want to have 4 ads displayed, and if there are empty slots, fill those with "your ad here"?  One for each slot empty?

Comment: Brad thanks it worked fine but still there is something missing out there when I insert any rows to mysqli it hide the "add you ads here" again which is not right it should become 2 text "ad your ads here" I updated my code above for you to see what I did wrong. thanks

Comment: @YousefAltaf, I don't understand.  How many rows are coming back from your query?  How many do you expect to be displayed?  How many "your ad here" ads do you expect to be displayed?

Comment: now I have two rows in my table and they are coming and displaying OK so I expect to have the other two as "ad your ads here" now what I got is the two rows which I have it in my table and nothing else

Comment: Brad if the table is empty it get me the 4 text of "add your ads here" but if there is one row in the table it just display this one row.

Comment: @YousefAltaf, Take the `else` out and always do the `for` loop with "your ad here".

Comment: yes Thanks Brad it worked perfect thanks again for your help Allah bless you brother.